# can not get session in PHP

Tags: security, session

In opera browser, I can not get session. I have the error  words

> this set-cookie was not sent over a secure connection and would have"

[image: error image]

i have checked the value default of `session_get_cookie_params['secure']` is false.

and i have set session that i dont use "secure" , but it does not work.

```
$currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params( 
 $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
 $currentCookieParams["path"], 
 $currentCookieParams['domain'], 
 false ,
 $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 0);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 0);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

I always cant get session , the `PHPSESSID` has been set secure automatically.

Comment: Any luck with other browsers?

Comment: Possibly caching issue. Try using the Incognito Opera or delete cookies from the browser